# Python & Algorithm: plot simple shapes with disordered points

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to plot simple shapes with disordered points. For example

```
L_shape = [(0,0),(0,3),(1,3),(1,1),(3,1),(3,0)]
concave = [(0,0),(0,3),(1,3),(1,1),(2,1),(2,3),(3,3),(3,0)]

import random
disordered_concave = concave.copy()
random.shuffle(disordered_concave) # => [(1, 3), (2, 1), (0, 3), (2, 3), (0, 0), (3, 3), (3, 0), (1, 1)]
```

For ordered points, a simple shape could be drawn like
[image]

But with `disordered points`, it becomes

[image]

So How can I reorder these points to plot the original shapes?

I think there may be `multiple shapes` for `one points set`. So maybe we can consider adding more inputs? like:

1. Give a `point` inside the shape
2. Shapes with most angles with `90 degree`
3. All points are on the shape edge (not within), and `area max`

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. According to [this](http://study.com/academy/lesson/concave-convex-polygons-definition-examples.html), we cannot determine exactly what concave polygon look like, so your problem seems impossible to solve.

Comment: @PhamTrung, so what about the `additionals`? Will that help?

Comment: Most angles 90º or ALL angles 90º? If the former, I don't think the problem has solution, if the latter, we can give it a try.

Comment: @Jblasco I feel the possible `shapes`(closure shape, lines connecting all points, with no cross) should be limited. Within these shapes, with most angles with 90 degree,  I feel could give pretty good results in my case.

Comment: Even if you fix all angles to 90°, there can be multiple shapes, even with the same area. None of that really suffices to define a unique polygon, so that won't be enough if that is your goal. If you count point symmetric polygons as one, even then you won't get unique solutions.

Comment: @G.Bach well..then maybe I'll just return all of them. Because in my case, the input will not be that versatile.

Comment: how many points per shape?

Comment: @Jblasco I think will be less than 15

Comment: For concave,  each order of points can be a valid shape, so you can have 15! solutions, which is > 10^12